# Reserve stock on order complete not working

Tags: 8, commerce

I am working on Commerce 2.x and I am trying to reduce the stock value when someone adds an item in the cart. When I check the stock config there is an option to check the `Reserve the stock on order complete` Will that option do the same functionality. If yes, I am unable to see the reduced stock value when any item in the cart.

Comment: “on order complete” happens after checkout, “item in the cart” happens before

Comment: @Clive, Is that possible to reserve the stock while adding the item into the cart?

Comment: You will have to implement the same functionality when it is added to the cart yourself - however think about why you need this to happen as  what If you have 10 in stock then I add 10 to my cart but not checkout — leaving you with 10 things to sell and no way to sell it ??!! Probably best to only remove stock after some one pays for the item?